# How to add a second condition in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query in my controller and it is working fine,

```
var Engineers = dbcontext.Employees.Where(i => i.Department == "Engineers");
```

but I would like to add a second condition to the query to filter out the results,

```
var Engineers = dbcontext.Employees.Where(i => i.Department == "Engineers" && i.UserStatus = 1);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's how you do it. Except you want to use `==` to compare values instead of `=` (assignment operator).

Comment: Typo.  You're trying to *assign* instead of *compare*.  Use the `==` operator that you were already using previously.

Comment: Thanks nbokmans, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo, just need to use comparison operator (==) instead of assignation (=)

So it would be like that:

```
var Engineers = dbcontext.Employees.Where(i => i.Department == "Engineers" && i.UserStatus == 1);
```